# Notification Count in Title

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, window-title

Is it possible to include in the Title tag the number of notifications a user has? For example, say a user has 5 notifications in their inbox. The title would have `(5)` right before the rest of the title. In the case that there are no notifications, it would look normal.

This would allow users to be able to have a Stack Exchange page (from any Stack Exchange site) open and be doing something else and monitor their notifications. If they see they get a new one, they can quickly switch to the tab and see what it was.

I would think that this would be easy to implement. Assuming that there is a variable that holds how many notifications are in the inbox (used at the time for displaying that number on the inbox icon), you guys could call for that variable in the beginning of the Title tag. Here is an example, say the assumed variable is called inboxNotif and is in PHP.

```
<title>(<?php echo $inboxNotif; ?>) <?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

I am assuming that `<?php echo $title; ?>` is also used in displaying the title of the page; even if it is not, it is still there for demonstrative purposes. Nonetheless, the concept is there.